# Linking Error dlib C++, Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 7

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, dlib

I am trying to compile and run face_detection_ex.cpp from dlib examples folder.
But I am getting a lot of linking error example - dlib::image_window_.. 
. I tried libraries like -luser32 -lws2_32 -lgdi32 -lcomctl32 -limm32 but VScoundt find it.

Comment: Well, how about trying to link with dlib, which apparently is the library you're using, instead of the other libraries that you've tried? I'm unfamiliar with dlib. But it does look as if its name is dlib.

Comment: Amending the previous comment: apparently dlib is provided [as source code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928586/usage-of-dlib-library-in-visual-studio-2010?rq=1).

Comment: It doesn't have dll all source files .. @Cheersandhth.-Alf

Comment: if the link solved your problem then let's close this as a duplicate. Does that solution work?

Comment: The link try to compile it using cmake, that I don't want to use. I followed the process listed by dlib http://dlib.net/compile.html. This worked fine for me, I believe the error was because of the Visual Studio was not updating the changes. I just closed the solution and opened it . But yes we can close it I don't know it is duplicate or not.