# How to setup Dlib with Visual Studio 2013 without CMake?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, dlib

- The official [**document**](http://dlib.net/compile.html) of dlib is shown as follow:

All you need to do is create an empty console project. Then add **dlib/all/source.cpp** to it and add the folder containing the **dlib folder** to the #include search path. Then you can compile any example program by adding it to your project.

Again, note that dlib will only be able to work with jpeg and png files if you link in libjpeg and libpng. In Visual Studio, the easiest way to do this is to add all the source files in the dlib/external folder into your project and also define the **DLIB_PNG_SUPPORT** and **DLIB_JPEG_SUPPORT** preprocessor directives. If you don't know how to configure Visual Studio then you should use CMake as shown above since it will take care of everything automatically.

- But you'll get less help according to those descriptions. What worse thing is this document is only for Visual Studio 2010, but I want to setup Dlib in the version 2013. So, how to setup without CMake?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

- I think I found the answer in https://github.com/aleen42/PersonalWiki/blob/master/qa/dlib.md

Answer (score 0):

I've written a tutorial at https://theprosperousheartblog.wordpress.com/2016/10/20/how-to-setup-dlib-c-in-the-visual-studio-2013/

I still use CMake, but I use it for creating a Visual Studio Project. CMake is great, everything is automatical. After creating a Visual Studio Project using CMake, you can do your work on the project normally in Visual Studio.